# Build time error occuring when changed multiple catch blocks to single catch using "when"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**I changed the catch block from commented lines to the not commented lines. After change visual studio not showing any error message ,but after build it shows the errors in image**

```
try
                        {
                            var settings = (from u in db.UserSettings
                                            where u.UserId == userID
                                            select u).Single();

                            settings.CurrentPageId = PageID;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) when (ex is InvalidOperationException || ex is ArgumentNullException || ex is Exception)
                        //catch (InvalidOperationException) 
                        //{
                        //    // No setting saved before. Create default setting
                        //    UserSetting newSetting = new UserSetting();
                        //    newSetting.UserId = userID;
                        //    newSetting.CurrentPageId = PageID;

                        //    db.UserSettings.InsertOnSubmit(newSetting);
                        //    db.SubmitChanges();
                        //}
                        //catch(ArgumentNullException)
                        //{
                        //    // No setting saved before. Create default setting
                        //    UserSetting newSetting = new UserSetting();
                        //    newSetting.UserId = userID;
                        //    newSetting.CurrentPageId = PageID;

                        //    db.UserSettings.InsertOnSubmit(newSetting);
                        //    db.SubmitChanges();
                        //}
                        //catch(Exception)
                        {
                            // No setting saved before. Create default setting
                            UserSetting newSetting = new UserSetting();
                            newSetting.UserId = userID;
                            newSetting.CurrentPageId = PageID;

                            db.UserSettings.InsertOnSubmit(newSetting);
                            db.SubmitChanges();
                        }
```

[its the error showing but the brackets are correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tNwW.png)

Comment: Your code is working when I copied it into a new blank console app. Try cleaning and rebuilding your solution and make sure you do not have any errors around the try-catch block (Just make sure that it builds when you comment the WHOLE thing)

Comment: Most of the time, the first error is the one causing the issue, take a look at that first.